# ReactJs Map if/else

Tags: reactjs

I am new in Reactjs. So i have a list of Restaurants like that

```
const restaurants = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Restaurant-1",
        oras: "Constanta",
        background: "url(" + restaurant1 + ")",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Restaurant-2",
        oras: "Constanta",
        background: "url(" + restaurant2 + ")",
      },
```

Where i used map to populate my restaurantlist

```
  const restaurantlist = restaurants.map((restaurant) => (
if(name=="something")      
<Restaurant
        src={background}
        key={restaurant.id}
        restaurant={restaurant}
      />
    ));
```

But i dont want to add all objects, i want to add only objects where their name=="something"
Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return an expression when you use that condition :

```
  const restaurantlist = restaurante.map((restaurant) => (name=="something" ? 
      <Restaurant
        src={background}
        key={restaurant.id}
        restaurant={restaurant}
      />:null
    ));
```

or

```
const restaurantlist = restaurants.map((restaurant) => {
  if(name=="something"){      
      <Restaurant
        src={background}
        key={restaurant.id}
        restaurant={restaurant}
      />
   } else{
       return null;
   }
 });
```

Comment: may I ask you to have a look  at a react.js related question here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64067097/simple-html-element-in-react-js-code-does-not-work-in-xampp-localhost ?